# ASP.NET Core - Get client's IP address instead of local IP

Tags: c#, .net, docker, http, ip

I am trying to retrieve the client's IP address in my .net backend, which is running in Docker.

With the code snippet below, I would expect to get the IP address of the client but I get `172.17.0.1` instead, which is some local IP address (Docker probably).

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var clientIpContext = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.MapToIPv4().ToString();

            ...
            
            await _next(context);
        }
```

I hope someone can help :)

Comment: You will most likely need to find the `X-Forwarded-For` in the context to be able to figure out the caller's IP address.

Comment: @Jawad sadly, I'm only seing the local addresses: https://ibb.co/DWpxSNX

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with docker, but most proxies forwarding on HTTP requests will populate the X-Forwarded-For header with the original originating IP address.

You could check the incoming request for that header to see if your client IP address is there.

Comment: I'm not seeing the X-Forwarded-For header in the httpContext. I checked the complete request, but I'm only seeing the local IP: https://ibb.co/5nmrRRh